# Which of these functions are tail recursive?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, tail-recursion

```
let rec f1 = fun x -> if x = 0 then 1 else f1 (f1 0) in ...

let rec f2 = fun x -> if x = 0 then foo x else f2 x in ...
```

where foo isn't tail recursive

```
let rec f3 = fun x -> if x = 0 then foo x else f3 x in ...
```

where foo is tail recursive

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: none of those are actually recursive at all, since x is passed as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be asking whether the function is tail recursive.  You should be asking whether *all calls are tail calls*.  Additionally, whether `foo` is tail recursive or not is actually not relevant—a tail call is a tail call irrespective of which function it calls.

So let's take them one at a time:

```
let rec f1 = fun x -> if x = 0 then 1 else f1 (f1 0) in ...
```

In the `else`, the inner call to `f1` is not a tail call.  The outer one is.  Note that this means that, depending on how you define the term, you could either say that this function *is* tail recursive (it's got a tail call to itself) or that it isn't (it's got a non-tail call to itself).

This is why it's important to focus on *which calls are tail calls*, not tail recursion!  A language with tail-call elimination will do it for the outer call but not the inner one.

```
let rec f2 = fun x -> if x = 0 then foo x else f2 x in ...
let rec f3 = fun x -> if x = 0 then foo x else f3 x in ...
```

The calls to `foo` and to `f2` are tail calls in both cases.  Again, it doesn't matter what `foo` is.

Answer (score 0):

All of them are tail recursive.

`f1` however does contain two recursive calls, of which only the outer is a tail call.

For `f2`/`f3`, it does not matter whether `foo` is tail-recursive or not, because it is not part of the recursion of `f2`/`f3` at all.